# Redux thunk – Proper implementation

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

My implementation of the redux thunk is causing to override the array data.

Obviously something is wrong in the flow but I cant figured it out.

Basically I have two components **StringInstrument** and **UsersListedItems**.

**StringInstrument** will fetch data from DB (via axios) to get a list of item owners.

For each owner a **UsersListedItems** component will be created and this component will also fetch data from DB (images) via the owner ID.

So I would say that **StringInstrument** actually creating the **UsersListedItems**.

Here is some code for **StringInstrument**:

```
if (this.props.error) {
        return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
    }
    if (this.props.isLoading) {
        return <CircularProgress/>;
    }

     return (
        <div>
            <Grid container spacing={24}>
                {this.props.itemOwner.map((item, index) => (
                    <Grid item xs={6} sm={3} key={index}>
                        <UsersListedItems
                            ownerId={item.ownerId}
                            userName={item.userName}
                            categoryId={1}>
                        </UsersListedItems>
                    </Grid >)
                )}
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
   }
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    itemOwner: state.itemOwner.data,
    isLoading: state.itemOwner.isLoading,
    error: state.itemOwner.error
}
 }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
    getItemOwners: (id) => dispatch(itemAction.getItemOwners(id))
  }
```

This is how I implemented the action & reducer.

```
export function getItemOwner(state = initState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ITEM_OWNER_START:
        state = Object.assign({}, state, { isLoading: true });
        break;
    case GET_ITEM_OWNER_SUCCESS:
        state = Object.assign({}, state, { data: action.payload, isLoading: false });
        break;
    case GET_ITEM_OWNER_ERROR:
        state = Object.assign({}, state, { error: action.payload, isLoading: false });
        break;
}
return state;
 }

 export function getItems(state = initState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ITEMS_START:
        state = Object.assign({}, state, { isLoading: true });
        break;
    case GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS:
        state = Object.assign({}, state, { data: action.payload, isLoading: false });
        break;
    case GET_ITEMS_ERROR:
        state = Object.assign({}, state, { error: action.payload, isLoading: false });
        break;
}
return state;


export const getItemOwners = (categoryId) => {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    //make async call to database
    dispatch({ type: GET_ITEM_OWNER_START });
    axios.get('api/items/owner/category/' + categoryId)
        .then(function (response) {
            dispatch({ type: GET_ITEM_OWNER_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            dispatch({ type: GET_ITEM_OWNER_ERROR, payload: error });
        });
}
 };

  export const getItems = (categoryId, ownerId) => {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_ITEMS_START });
    axios.get('api/items/' + categoryId + '/' + ownerId)
        .then(function (response) {
            dispatch({ type: GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            dispatch({ type: GET_ITEMS_ERROR, payload: error });
        });
}
```

I am not sure how to manage\control the flow of the dispatchers in order so it will fit to the component structure without override the collected data.

As you can see in the attach image the 4 'GET_ITEM_SUCCESS' are at the end and each one of them will override the next one.

[image]

Hope I was clear and apologized for this long code example.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is that you're only storing one of the items in state at any given time, and each subsequent call is clobbering the content in state.  If I'm correct in that assumption, then the solution would be to use categoryId and ownerId as a key for storing the data in an object where the value would be the payload.

First you'll need to provide the categoryId and ownerId in the action

```
export const getItems = (categoryId, ownerId) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: GET_ITEMS_START, categoryId, ownerId });
  axios.get('api/items/' + categoryId + '/' + ownerId)
    .then(function (response) {
      dispatch({ type: GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data, categoryId, ownerId });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      dispatch({ type: GET_ITEMS_ERROR, payload: error, categoryId, ownerId });
    });
```

Next, you'll need to update your reducer to assign the payload to an object

```
const key = `${action.categoryId}-${action.ownerId}`; // unique key for the payload
switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ITEMS_START:
        state = Object.assign({}, state, { isLoading: true, data: Object.assign({}, state.data, {[key]: []}) });
        break;
    case GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS:
        state = Object.assign({}, state, { data: Object.assign({}, state.data, { [key]: action.payload }), isLoading: false });
        break;
    case GET_ITEMS_ERROR:
        state = Object.assign({}, state, { error: action.payload, isLoading: false });
        break;
}
```

Finally, you'll need to map the data to the state of your component via props (redux). Then you can access the items using the same key items[`${categoryId}-${ownerId}`]

Comment: Hello Rob, Thank you very much for our help. Now I can align the data with the specific owner. There is one more problem since I am using a loop I will be able to render only one UsersListedItems component.  Do you have any suggestion regarding a better code design for this. Thank you

Comment: I would replace the ownerId and categoryId on the UserLIstedItems component with `items={items[`${categoryId}-${ownerId}`]}` as a prop.  That way the component could iterate over the items and render a list

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate your help.